# React Material - MUIDataTable - Is there a way to have the row count in the header?

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

Does anyone know of a way to include the row count in the header? 
I do not seem to be able to do this using the **options** or **columns** properties.

What I am trying to achieve is:

Column 1 Header (***ROW COUNT***)  | Column 2 Header | ...... | Column N Header

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

More info:

1. [What I am trying to achieve in a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiV4q.png)
2. [Trying to get a working copy of my app in SandBox and will post back. Current sandbox shows the options and columns options used](https://codesandbox.io/s/niswork-muidatatables-customized-header-with-count-4zm46)

Comment: WHat have you tried so far ? can you post some code ? or a codesandbox that we can use to start ? or a picture of what you want

Comment: @Incepter Apologies for the "incomplete" question.

Comment: have found that the info required for this to work is part of the "tableState" state/property which is available as a prop in the onTableChange table property, but does not seem to be a part of the header/column options. What I am trying to achieve is have a header with the following format:  Header Name ( number of filter records / total number of records)

Comment: I think you should create your own header since you have the required props

Comment: @incepter So as mentioned, I have considered this option, however I am a bit perplexed with how to implement it as: when trying to create a custom header using the "customHeadRender" I do not seem to have access to the tableState (see CodeSandBox in original question). Apologies if the above seems trivial but I am quite new in React and trying to wrap my head around how this library works. Any help/insight will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example:

```
import React from "react";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

export default class MuiDatatableHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filteredRowCount: 0
        }
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
            {
                label: "Name",
                name: "Name",
                options: {
                    customHeadRender: (columnMeta, updateDirection) => (
                        `${columnMeta.name} (Total Count ${data.length})`
                    )
                }
            },
            {
                label: "Title", name: "Title",
                options: {
                    customHeadRender: (columnMeta, updateDirection) => (
                        `${columnMeta.name} (Total Filter Row Count ${this.state.filteredRowCount})`
                    )
                }
            },
            {name: "Location"},
            {name: "Age"},
            {name: "Salary"}
        ];
        const data = [
            ["Gabby George", "Business Analyst", "Minneapolis", 30, "$100,000"],
            ["Aiden Lloyd", "Business Consultant", "Dallas", 55, "$200,000"]
        ];

        const options = {
            selectableRows: "multiple",
            selectableRowsHeader: data.length > 0,
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({filteredRowCount: 10})
                }}>Filter data
                </button>
                <MUIDataTable
                    title={"ACME Employee list"}
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already tired your proposed solution and the problem is that it only displays the total number of records. What I am after is something like (number of filtered records)/(total number of records). This info is part of the ***tableState*** property/state and more specifically of ***tableState.displayData*** but the state is not accessible from properties such as ***customHeadRender***.

Comment: @Nikolaos, I have updated my answer where I put a state variable `filteredRowCount ` under state and I updated data of `filteredRowCount ` using button click. Then the `filteredRowCount ` is shown in `Title` column header. Hope it helps you

Comment: I am not sure you understand what I am trying to achieve, maybe I am not explaining it properly. What I am looking for is to be able when filtering that the number of filtered rows shows in the header in the format of ***(number of filtered records)/(total number of records)***. Your method just sets the state to a predefined number.

Comment: Yes I completely understand what you said earlier and that's why I have given you this example as I cannot give exact example what you are looking for. Here you will set your filtered result in state and then you can show **(number of filtered records)/(total number of records)** from the state that you already set after filtering.